# On click,redirect to a new page and scroll to a particular div on that new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollview

Requirement : I want to redirect to a new page on click of a button and then I want to scroll to a particular section on the new page.

Issue :

This is how I'm currently redirecting

```
 <div class="button know-more-btn">  
    <a href="/about-us#Who-We-Are" target="" class="btn-link btn-small">
    KNOW MORE</a>
    </div>
```

Now once it redirects on click of the button,I want it to to scroll to a particular section on the new page.

I'm currently trying to achieve this scenario with the below code :-

```
$('.know-more-btn').click(function () {
   if(location.hash == "#Who-We-Are"){
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".map-section").offset().top
}, 1000);
}
});
```

So on click of the know-more-btn,it should check the location.hash and scroll to the map-section div class on the new page.

But it only redirects and does not scroll to the desired section.

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
$('.know-more-btn').click(function () {
   if(location.hash == "#Who-We-Are"){
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".map-section").offset().top
}, 1000);
}
});
```

New code:

```
   if(location.hash == "#Who-We-Are"){
       $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(".map-section").offset().top
   }, 1000);


   $('.know-more-btn').click(function () {
      if(location.hash == "#Who-We-Are"){
       $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(".map-section").offset().top
     }, 1000);
    }
   });
```

Comment: But location.hash will only return "#Who-We-Are" .I want to scroll to a particular div called .map-section after redirecting to /about-us#Who-We-Are.How will I scroll to that particular div is my question

Comment: @amy i've just updated my code specifically for #Who-We-Are, give it a try

Comment: @amy just copied the `if` from your click event, to above, so when the page loads and the hash is there, it will trigger the `if`

Comment: Your code scroll to who-we-are section.I want it to go to a specific div (.map-section) which is on the same page .My requirement is that on click of the know more button,I want it to redirect it to the about-us#Who-We-Are (which it does obviously) AND then scroll to the div (.map-section)which is a PART of the who-we-are page.

Comment: if this code `if(location.hash == "#Who-We-Are"){
       $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(".map-section").offset().top
   }, 1000);` is executed in the `/about` page it will scroll to `.map-section` for users that click know-more-btn

Comment: You can remove the code from the click, i just left untouched your code.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this, there's a built in method on every `HTMLElement` called `scrollIntoView`

Add the following script to your about-us page:

```js
const map = document.querySelector('#Who-We-Are .map-section')

// simulates arriving at #Who-We-Are for the purpose of this example
window.location.hash = 'Who-We-Are';

addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
  if (window.location.hash === 'Who-We-Are') {
    map.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start"});
  }
});
```

```css
#Who-We-Are {
  margin-top: 110vh;
}

.map-section {
  margin-top: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<section id="Who-We-Are">
  <h2>Who We Are</h2>
  <div class="map-section">Map</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I want to scroll to a particular section ('.map-section') div on the about-us#Who-We-Are page

Comment: In that case just select for the particular element you want to scroll to. answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

this jquery/javascript code will help you

```
    function hashchanged(){
        if(location.hash.substr(1)!='') $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: ($('#'+location.hash.substr(1)).position().top-200) }, 'slow');
    }
    $(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
        hashchanged();
    });
    hashchanged();
```

Any question im here.

Answer (score 0):

this is my best solution which i had never seen this before. maybe this helpful for you.

below code for the page from that i want to redirect on click a link.

```
<div ><a onclick="myHash()"></a></div>
```

this is to redirect to a new page and send hash through url.

```
     function myHash() {
      $(document).ready(function () {
                
                  window.location.href="contact.html#link"
      });
  }

     }
```

And On new page which i want open and scroll to the specific div.

```
<div id="link"></div>
```

And using url's hash to scroll specific div on new page

```
 $(document).ready(function() {    
    if (window.location.hash) {
           setTimeout(function() {
               $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
               $('html, body').animate({
                   scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
                   }, 1500)
           }, 0);
       }
       
   });
```